# JavaScript JSON associative object key and value both as datetime stamp

Tags: javascript, php

My variable `date_mplayer` simply stores a PHP generated `time()` stamp. I need to create an array with a key/value pair which both the key and value are initially the same time stamp from `date_mplayer`.

What I've got at the moment:

```
var md = {date_mplayer:date_mplayer};
localStorage.setItem('date_mplayer', JSON.stringify(md));
```

If I `console.log(localStorage);` I get...

```
date_mplayer "{"date_mplayer":1427837963}"
```

What I need should look something like:

```
date_mplayer "{1427837963:1427837963}"
```

Background: this is how I will pass function commands to a music player across tabs based on each tab's assigned date. Every X number of seconds the JSON object will be reconstructed with the updated timestamp for the tab's key representation; tabs not updated within a span of time a few seconds longer will have their keys removed (to prevent eternal growth until it hits the browser storage limit).

No frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var md = {};
md[date_mplayer] = date_mplayer;
localStorage.setItem('date_mplayer', JSON.stringify(md));
```

Answer (score 1):

Object keys, when written in object literal syntax, are non-dynamic; that is to say, you can't use variables in their place. The key will be named literally what you type there, so:

```
var foo = 'bar', obj = {foo: foo};
obj.foo; //bar
obj.bar; //undefined
```

Instead, to set a dynamic key name, you need to set the key via square-bracket syntax after the object has been created, passing the key name as a string:

```
var foo = 'bar', obj = {};
obj[foo] = foo;
obj.bar; //bar
```